# IE process memory usage keep growing for our website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, caching, memory-leaks

We have an angular 1.5 client and asp.net mvc application. We are currently facing an issues where when we refresh (F5) the page the memory usage shown in the windows task keep growing (20-50mb). When we reach around 1go to 1.2go memory usage, we start having troubles, scripts are not loading properly or the user have major slowdown.

Users are using IE11 and we don't need to support lower  versions.

I tried different methods to pinpoint the problem but without any conclusions.

Observation 1 : When the developer console is closed, when I press F5, the memory seem to reset as it should. (but our user doesn't use the console...)

Observation 2 : When I take a memory snapshot in the developer tools, it takes around 20-60mb which is the average amount it goes up each time.

Observation 3 : The average memory usage when everything seem to be working fine is around 100-250mb.

Observation 4 : Caching options does seem to have any impact whether i choose to reset at each time i visit to never.

Observation 5 : In chrome, the memory seem to grow, but automatically reset itself when it reach around 600mb.

From these observations, I am not sure if the problem lies in the application or in custom or IE caching. I suppose there is some kind of caching mechanism is causing me some trouble because the web page snapshot is 20mb-60mb which is far of the process memory after a while and if it was a memory leak i would expect my page to grow and not only the process.

What are the differences between the webpage memory vs the process memory? It might help me to make better conclusions.

What are the tools that could help me to pinpoint this issues?

Thanks

Comment: This is an excellent post about finding memory leaks on angular apps: http://www.dwmkerr.com/fixing-memory-leaks-in-angularjs-applications/